# What should I do to make this calculator work?

Tags: calculator, basic

I have to program a simple calculator in BASIC that asks for a number, then for a basic operator (+,-,*,/), then for another number, then another operator until the user inputs "=" as an operator. Then the program should stop and output the result. So far, I have done this :

```
10 Input "Entrez un nombre                   : " ; Nombre
20 Input "Entrez un opérateur (+,-,*,/)      : " ; Operateur$
if Operateur$ <> "+" and Operateur$ <> "-" and Operateur$ <> "*" and Operateur$ <> "/" and Operateur$ <> "=" then goto 20
if Operateur$ = "+" or Operateur$ = "-" or Operateur$ = "*" or Operateur$ = "/" then goto 10
if Operateur$ = "=" then goto 30
30 Print "Résultat                           : " ; Resultat
```

I am stuck at how to actually calculate the result, I cannot figure out a way...

Comment: What platform and what version of which BASIC interpreter are you using?

Comment: I use Just BASIC v 2.0

Answer (score 0):

```
10 Input "Entrez un nombre                   : " ; Nombre
    Resultat = Nombre
20 Input "Entrez un opérateur (+,-,*,/)      : " ; Operateur$
    if Operateur$ <> "+" and Operateur$ <> "-" and Operateur$ <> "*" and Operateur$ <> "/" and Operateur$ <> "=" then goto 20
    if Operateur$ = "+" or Operateur$ = "-" or Operateur$ = "*" or Operateur$ = "/" then goto 30
    if Operateur$ = "=" then goto 40 else goto 30
30 Input "Entrez un nombre                   : " ; Nombre2
    if Operateur$ = "+" then Resultat = Resultat + Nombre2
    if Operateur$ = "-" then Resultat = Resultat - Nombre2
    if Operateur$ = "*" then Resultat = Resultat * Nombre2
    if Operateur$ = "/" then Resultat = Resultat / Nombre2
goto 20
40 Print "Résultat                           : " ; Resultat
```